# Gaussian Blur over MKMapKit

Tags: ios, mapkit, gpuimage

It seems like everything I've found for Gaussian blur requires an image or video like GPUImage. Does anyone know of either a fork of GPUimage or an approach for placing a gaussian blur over a region of an MKMapKit map?  The goal is that the map can still be zoomed and dragged around without noticeable lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try an approach of taking a snapshot of the map by asking its layer to `renderInContext` and handing those contents over to GPUImage. This should be performant.

Comment: Thanks @incanus for the tip - I created a new "blurredMapControl" class function to my MKMapView subclass with your suggestions and it works great, at least on the iPhone 5S. Testing with the iPhone 4 shortly and if all is well I'll share some code.